# ActiveSupport::Duration hours/minutes/seconds is always seconds?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activesupport

If I have an `ActiveSupport::Duration` and call hours/minutes/seconds on it, it always returns the number of seconds:

```rb
(8.hours + 1.second).parts
=> {:hours=>8, :seconds=>1}
(8.hours + 1.second).seconds
=> 28801 seconds
(8.hours + 1.second).hours
=> 28801 hours
```

Is this the expected behavior? If yes, why? :)

Answer (score 2):

Looks like a bug.

I've searched for some reported bug related with this but there is no bug with this.

The closest one is this, but it's not the same.

https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/37450

Please create an issue with this in this format

https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/37607